# How does one make sense of a delta function of a scalar field?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, probability, dirac-delta-distributions, stochastic-processes

Disclaimer: Originally posted on math SE, but thought that it was better in physics SE, so deleted my post on math SE and posted here.

In the classic review summary of stochastic quantization [here](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/helmuth.hueffel/PhysRep.pdf), in particular equation 3.14, in which the initial condition is given as:
\begin{equation}
P(\phi,0)= \prod\limits_{x} \delta(\phi(x)). \tag{3.14}
\end{equation}
I don't really understand the product because it seems that $\phi(x)$ is a scalar field defined over all of $\mathbb{R}^n$, so I'm not sure how to interpret the product over all $x$. Additionally, what does the delta function mean in this context (that the inputted $\phi = 0$)?

I spent a long time pouring over related literature and couldn't find an explanation of this, so any insight into this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related: [Can operators be argument of Dirac Delta function](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/199757/50583)

Comment: I'm not sure about the product, but one notion that might be relevant is the functional delta function. This is defined to be a "functional distribution" so that $\int \mathcal{D}\phi\mathcal{F[\phi]} \delta(\phi - \phi') = \mathcal{F}[\phi']$ i.e it picks out a specific field configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ref.1 is already in eq. (3.1) considering a [functional integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_integration) over the scalar field $\phi:M\to \mathbb{R}$. Here $M$ is spacetime. For a rigorous treatment of functional integrals, Ref. 1 points in the beginning of Section 3 to its Ref. [3.2]. In this answer we will just take an intuitive heuristic approach, and try to construct the functional integral as an appropriate continuum limit of a discretized space-time.

In more detail, if $x_i\in M$ denotes a discrete spacetime point labelled by an index $i\in I$ in a finite index set $I$, then the probability distribution $P$ becomes a (possibly [generalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29)) function

$$P: ~\mathbb{R}^{|I|}\times \mathbb{R}~\longrightarrow~\mathbb{R} ,$$

and eq. (3.14) reduces to a finite product of [Dirac distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)

$$P(\phi,t\!=\!0)~=~ \prod\limits_{i\in I} \delta(\phi_i), \qquad \phi_i~:= ~\phi(x_i),\tag {3.14'}$$

which is now well-defined. Here the parameter $t$ is a 'fiducial' time that should not be confused with time in the spacetime $M$.

Eq. (3.14') becomes the statement that the probability distribution $P$ has 'initial' [support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_%28mathematics%29#Support_of_a_distribution) at $\phi=0$.

To get finite probabilities one should integrate the probability density $P$ over the variables $\phi_i$, $i\in I$. In other words, ultimately, we want to insert $P$ as an integrand into the functional integral over $\phi$, cf. e.g. eq. (3.20).

References:

1. P.H. Damgaard & H. Huffel, *Stochastic Quantization,* Phys. Rep. 152 (1987) 227, ([pdf](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/helmuth.hueffel/PhysRep.pdf)).

Comment: Thanks! This was really helpful!! If I understood it correctly, since functional integration is not yet mathematically rigorous, we can start with finite index sets $I$. Do you know what possible sets $I$ are allowed? If all possible sets $I$ are allowed, then it seems to say the same as saying $\phi(x) = 0$ for all $x$?

Comment: I would upvote your comment, but don't have enough reputation points yet; will do when I have enough. Additionally, for understanding the delta function, does that mean $\delta(\phi) = \infty$ for $\phi(x) = 0$ for all $x$; otherwise $\delta(\phi) = 0$?

Comment: Finally, with regards to the support, the definition I have of support is that it is the set of $\phi$ such that $P(\phi, t) \neq 0$. So when you say initial support at $\phi = 0$, does that just mean that $P = \infty$ (importantly, $P \neq 0$)? Thanks so much!!

Comment: Mathematically, the Dirac delta distribution is a more sophisticated gadget than what you say in above comments, but heuristically speaking, you're right.

Comment: Thanks! And the paper doesn't seem to specify what finite index sets $I$ are used, so are all possible sets $I$ allowed?

Comment: Well, a particular discretization $I$ is just one out of many. At the end of the day, we are supposed to somehow define an appropriate continuum limit $|I|\to \infty$.